OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device) using Pyaudio in google collab
I am working on a Realtime speech emotion recognition using LSTM. I have used pydub library to capture the live  input speech . I am working with google collab . I am not sure that whether i am using the right runtime for this process or not .
Currently I am using "T4 GPU" hardware accelerator. I am encountering a issue with the pyaudio whenever  I am trying to open the input stream to capture the audio.
import pyaudio
import wave
from array import array
import struct
import time

# Initialize variables
RATE = 24414
CHUNK = 512
RECORD_SECONDS = 7.1

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt32
CHANNELS = 1
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILE = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/output.wav"

# Open an input channel
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


# Initialize a non-silent signals array to state "True" in the first 'while' iteration.
data = array('h', np.random.randint(size = 512, low = 0, high = 500))

# SESSION START
print("** session started")
total_predictions = [] # A list for all predictions in the session.
tic = time.perf_counter()

while is_silent(data) == False:
    print("* recording...")
    frames = [] 
    data = np.nan # Reset 'data' variable.

    timesteps = int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS) # => 339

    # Insert frames to 'output.wav'.
    for i in range(0, timesteps):
        data = array('l', stream.read(CHUNK)) 
        frames.append(data)

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILE, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

    print("* done recording")

    x = preprocess(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILE) # 'output.wav' file preprocessing.
    # Model's prediction => an 8 emotion probabilities array.
    predictions = model.predict(x, use_multiprocessing=True)
    pred_list = list(predictions)
    pred_np = np.squeeze(np.array(pred_list).tolist(), axis=0) # Get rid of 'array' & 'dtype' statments.
    total_predictions.append(pred_np)
    
    # Present emotion distribution for a sequence (7.1 secs).
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
    plt.bar(emo_list, pred_np, color = 'darkturquoise')
    plt.ylabel("Probabilty (%)")
    plt.show()
    
    max_emo = np.argmax(predictions)
    print('max emotion:', emotions.get(max_emo,-1))
    
    print(100*'-')
    
    # Define the last 2 seconds sequence.
    last_frames = np.array(struct.unpack(str(96 * CHUNK) + 'B' , np.stack(( frames[-1], frames[-2], frames[-3], frames[-4],
                                                                            frames[-5], frames[-6], frames[-7], frames[-8],
                                                                            frames[-9], frames[-10], frames[-11], frames[-12],
                                                                            frames[-13], frames[-14], frames[-15], frames[-16],
                                                                            frames[-17], frames[-18], frames[-19], frames[-20],
                                                                            frames[-21], frames[-22], frames[-23], frames[-24]),
                                                                            axis =0)) , dtype = 'b')
    if is_silent(last_frames): # If the last 2 seconds are silent, end the session.
        break

# SESSION END        
toc = time.perf_counter()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
wf.close()
print('** session ended')

# Present emotion distribution for the whole session.
total_predictions_np =  np.mean(np.array(total_predictions).tolist(), axis=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.bar(emo_list, total_predictions_np, color = 'indigo')
plt.ylabel("Mean probabilty (%)")
plt.title("Session Summary")
plt.show()

print(f"Emotions analyzed for: {(toc - tic):0.4f} seconds")

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyaudio is already the newest version (0.2.11-1.3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-97261d8a231f> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 # Open an input channel
     18 p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
---> 19 stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
     20                 channels=CHANNELS,
     21                 rate=RATE,

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py in __init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input, output, input_device_index, output_device_index, frames_per_buffer, start, input_host_api_specific_stream_info, output_host_api_specific_stream_info, stream_callback)
    439 
    440         # calling pa.open returns a stream object
--> 441         self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    442 
    443         self._input_latency = self._stream.inputLatency

OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)

I have tried  alternative approaches to check the audio devices connected to my device .
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    if dev.get('maxInputChannels') > 0:
        print(f"Device {i}: {dev.get('name')}")

After running the above chunk of code my output window is blank.

